# Asp.Net C# Changing language with dropdownlist JavaScript DataTables

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datatables, dropdown

I am working on a project. Since the project has multi-language support, I want the `datatable` language to change according to the value in the `dropdownlist`.

I wrote a JavaScript code, but this code works instantly and does not display the datatable afterwards.

[image]

ASP Code

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLang" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker w-auto form-control-sm" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddLang_SelectedIndexChanged">  
          <asp:ListItem Value="tr" data-icon="flag-icon flag-icon-tr mr-2" Text="<%$Resources:Resources, LangTR %>">  </asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="en" data-icon="flag-icon flag-icon-gb mr-2" Text="<%$Resources:Resources, LangEN %>"> English </asp:ListItem>  
       </asp:DropDownList>
```

JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $('#ddlLang').on('change value',  function () {
            var ddlvalue = $(this).val();
                if (ddlvalue == 'tr') {
                    $('#regIn').DataTable({
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": false,
                        "ordering": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "responsive": true,
                        "language": {
                            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json"
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (ddlvalue == 'en') {
                    $('#regIn').DataTable({
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": false,
                        "ordering": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "responsive": true,
                        "language": {
                            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.4/i18n/en-GB.json"
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.  First, you need to destroy a DataTable before you init Datatables on the same table again.  Also, you can reduce the redundancy of you initialization.  The only apparent difference is the `language.url` path, so you can use a variable in your initialization, and set that variable when the drop down list is changed.

A working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/wro98kc3/15/)

**HTML**

```
<select id=ddlLang>
  <option value="">Select Lang</option>
  <option value="German">German</option>
  <option value="Turkish">Turkish</option>
</select>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var urlVal = "";

//default init in English
$('#example').DataTable();

function initTable() {
  //test if Datatable already exists
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
    //if it exists, destroy
    $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
  }
//init the datatable
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": urlVal
    }
  });
}

$('#ddlLang').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  if (selected === "Turkish") {
    urlVal = "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json";
  } else if (selected === "German") {
  urlVal = "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
}

initTable();
});
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you for the example you have.

When I implement this example with asp.net, the page is refreshed on language changes.

But the datatable language remains english and does not change. for the ddlLang drop-down list. It should change according to the value there, but unfortunately there is no change.

Comment: @Mustafa - sounds like you need to do some debugging to determine why that's happening.  Perhaps verify that you've properly targeted the asp.net "table" (with Id or Class). You can use F12 develop tools to inspect the rendered HTML and verify you have the correct Id or Class.